# Raster clip using REST API with shapefile polygon

Tags: raster, geoserver, clip

I am using GeoServer for my project along with React and Leaflet (react-leaflet plugin ).

Is there a way to clip a raster stored in the GeoServer on the fly? I want to display the clipped raster in the frontend depending on the input. I have a shapefile according to whose polygon the raster must be clipped. Is there such functionality in GeoServer through which I can clip raster depending on the shapefile?

I have checked Stack Overflow and the GeoServer community but I am unable to find a solution to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the provided WPS `cropCoverage` process which take a raster and a polygon.